# И снова этот хитрый .htaccess и mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Нужно настроить .htaccess таким образом:
При обращении к http://mydev/ все запросы к несуществующим файлам перенаправлялись на index.php

При обращении к любому поддомену http://(.*).mydev/ перенаправление происходило к sub.php

При http://(.*).mydev/admin/ опять к index.php

Запарился уже не знаю как решить, помогите пожалуйсто

Answer (score 2):

первый вопрос: http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/ErrorDocument/ErrorDocument2.php

```
<Directory "/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</Directory>
```

Второй

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*?)\.mydev/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Третий

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*?)\.mydev/admin/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Причем общий вид должен быть такой:

```
# 1
<Directory "/">
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</Directory>

# 3
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*?)\.mydev/admin/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]

# 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*?)\.mydev/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sub.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Вроде бы всё верно